# RequireJS Case sensitivity - Locally vs Server

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I deployed my site online today, and for the longest time, I was getting the following error:

```
syntax error
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML…3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
```

I tried everything, and nothing seemed to help, even this [blog post](http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/09/syntax-error-break-on-this-error-doctype-html-public-w3cdtd-xhtml3orgtr-xhtml1-dtd-xhtml1-strictdtd/) that is supposedly the holy grail solution.

I eventually determined that the problem ran with the RequireJS, and it was trying to lazy-load a file with the path of `minicalendar/app`, but the file was located in `miniCalendar/app` (notice the camelCase difference).

Granted, I had a mistake in my file, and I should have used camelCase, but while I was working on this locally, the file was loading just fine (in fact it still does). So why is it that RequireJS is case sensitive on my server, but not when running locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you on a mac? I ran into this issue. My dev machine is a mac (case-insensitive) and production is Linux (case-sensitive) filenames.

Because it worked on the Mac w/ wrong path, I didn't catch it until it hit the Linux server.

Comment: Yeah, I am. Wow. Okay, I'll be extra careful with my paths from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It is the web server and web server OS or (browser OS in the case of local file:// URLs) that determines whether it is case sensitive or not.

If your local OS is not case sensitive (Windows is not case sensitive, but Unix is), then local `file://` URLs will not be case sensitive.

Whether or not your web server is case sensitive depends upon the web server and the web server OS.

---

So, it appears that your webserver/webserver OS is case sensitive, but your local computer system is not case sensitive and that's why one works and the other doesn't.  It has nothing to do with require.js.